# What complexity class does is this set of grammars? NL-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-grammars

> [The unrestricted grammars characterize the recursively enumerable languages. This is the same as saying that for every unrestricted grammar `G` there exists some Turing machine capable of recognizing `L(G)` and vice versa.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrestricted_grammar)

Context: Grammars are Turing-complete. Therefore complexity classes like NL have equivalences in grammars.

> [One important NL-complete problem is ST-connectivity (or "Reachability") (Papadimitriou 1994 Thrm. 16.2), the problem of determining whether, given a directed graph G and two nodes s and t on that graph, there is a path from s to t. ST-connectivity can be seen to be in NL, because we start at the node s and nondeterministically walk to every other reachable node. ST-connectivity can be seen to be NL-hard by considering the computation state graph of any other NL algorithm, and considering that the other algorithm will accept if and only if there is a (nondetermistic) path from the starting state to an accepting state.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NL-complete)

Given a directed graph, deciding if `a->b` is a directed path is NL-complete.

We will reduce the directed graph to a grammar rules with one symbol on each side:

For each directed edge in the graph, add a grammar rule. The directed edge `a->b` becomes the grammar rule `a|b`.

The NL-complete query becomes, "If I set `a` to the start symbol, can I derive symbol `b` using the grammar rules?"

Each grammar rule has one symbol on each side (i.e. `a|b`).

Therefore grammar rules with one symbol on each side is NL-complete.

Are grammars consisting only of rules with one symbol on each side NL-complete?

**Related questions:**

[What complexity class does is this set of grammars? L-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124375/what-complexity-class-does-is-this-set-of-grammars-l-complete)

[What complexity class does is this set of grammars? P-hard?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124378/what-complexity-class-does-is-this-set-of-grammars-p-hard)

[What complexity class does this correspond to?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124361/what-complexity-class-does-this-correspond-to)

Comment: Grammars can't be NL-complete.  Languages can be.  What language did you have in mind?

Comment: @D.W. Turing machines can decide questions about Turing machines. Grammars recognize languages. Can grammars recognize grammars? Can grammars be formulated as a language?

Comment: @D.W. The "computational hierarchy" (not sure what to call it) of L, NL, P, NP, etc. "manifests" from studying Turing machines or [logic/descriptive complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_complexity_theory). Since unrestricted grammars are Turing-complete, I was wondering how the "computational hierarchy" "manifests" with unrestricted grammars. This question attempts to "manifest" NL to unrestricted grammars.

Comment: @D.W. I suppose the "language" is the set of all grammars consisting of a start symbol (which would be a grammar rule), a target symbol (not a grammar rule; the start and target symbols correspond to the directed path we're querying for) and grammar rules with one symbol on each side (corresponding to directed edges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can build a reduction to show that the following problem is NL-complete:

> Given a grammar where every rule has the form $X \to Y$ or $X \to a$ where $X,Y$ range over nonterminals and $a$ ranges over terminals, and given a nonterminal $S$ and a terminal $a$, determine whether $S$ can derive $a$.

This problem is equivalent to testing whether $a$ is reachable from $S$ in the corresponding directed graph, which is exactly the ST-connectivity problem.

---

I didn't understand what you meant by `a|b`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had seen grammar rules written that way (`a|b`)!