# What complexity class is this set of grammars?

Tags: formal-grammars, complexity-classes

Given a grammar where every rule has the form $X \to YZ$, $XY \to Z$ or $X \to a$ where $X,Y,Z$ range over nonterminals and $a$ ranges over terminals, and given a nonterminal $S$ and a terminal $a$, determine whether $S$ can derive $a$.

What complexity class does this correspond to?

**Related questions:**

[What complexity class does is this set of grammars? L-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124375/what-complexity-class-does-is-this-set-of-grammars-l-complete)

[What complexity class does is this set of grammars? NL-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/what-complexity-class-does-is-this-set-of-grammars-nl-complete)

[What complexity class is this set of grammars? In between NL and P?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124378/what-complexity-class-does-is-this-set-of-grammars-p-hard/124379#124379)

[What complexity class is this set of grammars? RE?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124383/what-complexity-class-is-this-set-of-grammars-re)

Comment: If you allow $X \to \epsilon$, you get unrestricted grammars. In the other direction, every context-sensitive grammar can be put in your form.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: "In the other direction" Are you saying ((context-sensitve) < (this) < (Unrestricted)) or ((context-sensitve) = (this) < (Unrestricted))?

Comment: The first option.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: Thanks! Do we know ((this) < (Unrestricted)) vs ((this) <= (Unrestricted))? We could introduce a terminal to represent the empty string input so that every string has length at least 1.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: If we introduced a new terminal to represent the empty string, $e$, could we add one rule per non-terminal, $A$: $Ae \to A$ and generate the same strings?

Comment: Actually, you need $e$ to be nonterminal per your rules, but that's not a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

Every unrestricted grammar can be converted to one with the following types of rules:
$$
AB \to CD \\
A \to BC \\
A \to a \\
A \to \epsilon
$$
Wikipedia calls this [Kuroda normal form for unrestricted grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuroda_normal_form).

You can convert a rule of the form $AB \to CD$ to a pair of rules $AB \to X_{ABCD}$, $X_{ABCD} \to CD$. Following the OP's suggestion, we can convert $A \to \epsilon$ to the rule $A \to E$, and add rules $BE \to B$ and $EB \to B$ for any nonterminal $B$. This allows us to obtain a grammar in your form equivalent to the original one, up to not being able to generate $\epsilon$.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to point out that this implies that the associated complexity class is RE, to have a direct answer to the original question. Sorry if I'm wrong and this doesn't follow, but the restriction of not being able to generate $\epsilon$ shouldn't matter for this.

Comment: Right, I left this final step to the reader.