# What complexity class is this set of grammars? In between NL and P?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-grammars

Given a grammar where (every rule has the form $X \to YZ$, $XY \to Z$ or $X \to a$), (($X \to YZ$) implies ($X \to ZY$)) and (($XY \to Z$) implies ($YX \to Z$)) where $X,Y,Z$ range over nonterminals and $a$ ranges over terminals, and given a nonterminal $S$ and a terminal $a$, determine whether $S$ can derive $a$.

What complexity class does this correspond to?

It appears to be the problem of finding an "all-in-path" in a "3-digraph" (See: [Is there a name for this directed graph and path concept? 3-digraph and all-in-path?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633252/is-there-a-name-for-this-directed-graph-and-path-concept-3-digraph-and-all-in-p)).

**Related questions:**

[What complexity class does is this set of grammars? L-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124375/what-complexity-class-does-is-this-set-of-grammars-l-complete)

[What complexity class does is this set of grammars? NL-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/what-complexity-class-does-is-this-set-of-grammars-nl-complete)

[What complexity class is this set of grammars?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124361/what-complexity-class-does-this-correspond-to)

[What complexity class is this set of grammars? RE?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124383/what-complexity-class-is-this-set-of-grammars-re)

Answer (score 0):

This appears "almost P-complete".

I think this is existential and P-complete is universal.

This problem corresponds to, "given (1) a SAT problem, (2) a candidate solution, and (3) a variable A, does (A imply (not A))?" This problem shows the existence of a contradiction (for a single variable).

P-complete corresponds to "given (1) a SAT problem, and (2) a candidate solution, does there exist a variable X such that (X implies (not X))?" By showing there exists a solution, you show the non-existence of a contradiction (for all variables).

Sometimes it's easier to find a contradiction than a solution. Consider a Horn-SAT problem containing the clauses `A` and `(not A)`. You don't need to check the other clauses.

This assumes the original question is equivalent to finding an "all-in-path" in a "3-digraph" (See: [Is there a name for this directed graph and path concept? 3-digraph and all-in-path?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633252/is-there-a-name-for-this-directed-graph-and-path-concept-3-digraph-and-all-in-p)

Given a 3-SAT instance `S`, candidate solution `Candidate` and a target variable, `X`, does `X` imply not `X`?

We will construct a 3-digraph:

For each literal `A` and its negation `nA`, in `S`, create a vertex.

Rewrite each or-clause in `S`:

`(A or B or C)`

`((A or B) or C)`

`(not(not((A or B))) or C)`

`(not(not(A) and not(B))) or C)`

`(not(A) and not(B)) implies C)`

Since there are 6 permutations of `A`,`B`,`C`, there are 6 rewrites. For each rewrite, add 2 directed edges: `nA->C` and `nB->C`.

Create a new vertex, `Candidate`. For each literal `A` in `Candidate`, add a directed edge `Candidate->A`.

Create a new vertex, `XContradiction`. Add directed edges `X->Xcontradiction` `nX->Xcontradiction`.

(After adding edges, ensure this is a trigraph.)

Is there an all-in-path from `S` to `Xcontradiction`?

If we show the non-existence of an all-in-path for each literal (and not just `X`), then we have decided the corresponding P problem (does `Candidate` satisfy).