# What complexity class is this set of grammars? RE?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-grammars

Given a grammar where every rule has the form $X \to YZ$, $XY \to Z$, $X \to a$, or $X \to \epsilon$ where $X,Y,Z$ range over nonterminals and $a$ ranges over terminals, and given a nonterminal $S$ and a terminal $a$, determine whether $S$ can derive $a$.

(Thanks [Yuval Filmus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/683/yuval-filmus) for [pointing out this characterization - see first comment in linked question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124361/what-complexity-class-is-this-set-of-grammars))

What complexity class does this correspond to? RE?

**Related questions:**

[What complexity class does is this set of grammars? L-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124375/what-complexity-class-does-is-this-set-of-grammars-l-complete)

[What complexity class does is this set of grammars? NL-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/what-complexity-class-does-is-this-set-of-grammars-nl-complete)

[What complexity class is this set of grammars? In between NL and P?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124378/what-complexity-class-does-is-this-set-of-grammars-p-hard/124379#124379)

[What complexity class is this set of grammars?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124361/what-complexity-class-is-this-set-of-grammars)

Answer (score 2):

That grammar is unrestricted (not context free, as there are right hand sides shorter than the corresponding left hand side). The languages they generate are recursively enumerable, recursive only in special cases.

Comment: "The languages they generate are recursively enumerable" meaning equals RE or is a proper subset of RE?